# Как применять паттерн спецификация, если в реализации репозитория свои сущности

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, repository, ddd, спецификация

У меня есть доменная сущность User:

```cs
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool IsBanned { get; set; }
}
```

На уровне доступа к данным я использую ORM Entity Framework Core, соответственно там же есть сущность User для работы с ORM:

```cs
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public bool IsBanned { get; set; }
    public int? CurrentVkId { get; set; }
    public Vk? CurrentVk { get; set; }
    public List<Vk> Vks { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Subscribe> Subscribes { get; set; } = new();
}
```

И к примеру следующая спецификация (использую Ardalis.Specification):

```cs
public sealed class BannedUsersSpecification : Specification<User>
{
    public BannedUsersSpecification()
    {
        Query.Where(u => u.IsBanned);
    }
}
```

Спецификация написана именно для доменной сущности, как я могу применить ее для сущности, определенной в слое доступа к данным?

Я привел простой пример, а если бы у сущности домена были свойства, которые хранятся как-то по-другому в сущности EF, скажем, в JSON к примеру, как тогда применять спецификацию?

Или если бы мы вместо ORM использовали бы чистый SQL, что тогда?

Comment: Выделить интерфейс, который будут реализовывать как класс сущности, так и модель БД? Но у меня лично возникает вопрос: а зачем вам применять спецификацию бизнес-модели к модели хранения данных?

Comment: У меня есть домен со всеми сущностями. Домен ничего не знает о том, как реализовано хранение данных и какие там модели бд - это было бы нарушением принципа инверсии зависимостей. Спецификации относятся к предметной области - они должны находиться в домене и соответственно написаны должны быть для доменных сущностей.

Comment: Ну, вот вы и ответили на вопрос `"Спецификация написана именно для доменной сущности, как я могу применить ее для сущности, определенной в слое доступа к данным?"`. Ответ: никак. И не за чем, по большому счёту.

Comment: Незачем? Если вы используете сущности определенные в домене в связке с EF или другой ORM - вы нарушаете принцип единственной ответственности. У меня есть сущность User в домене с бизнес логикой и сущность User в слое доступа к данным. Во втором случае в сущности используются дополнительные навигационные свойства и атрибуты, которые я бы не мог использовать в доменной сущности - это лишние зависимости и опять же очень явное нарушение SRP.

Comment: Именно поэтому и нужно разделять бизнес-сущности (и их спецификации) и сущности слоя данных (и их спецификации)

Comment: Но сущности слоя данных и хранятся в слое данных. Тогда каким образом пользователь может в слое приложения или в слое домена получать данные с выборкой? Эти слои ничего не знают о слое доступа к данным.